# Python Selenium Geckodrive

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

Hey there just trying a basic browser launch using Firefox.
I've tried using executable path, if statement, and without an if statement and the browser will still not open. I've checked the shell and I don't have an error.My best guess is I'm missing an action of some sort I just need someone to point my in the right direction using my current code, thank you.

```
from selenium import webdriver 

class testbot():
    def botfox(self):
        driver = self.driver = webdriver.firfox(geckodriver)
        driver.get("https://wwww.google.com")

if __name__ == "__botfox__":
    botfox()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, try this :)

```
from selenium import webdriver 

class testbot():

    def botfox(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("https://wwww.google.com")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testBotInstace = testbot()
    testBotInstace.botfox()
```

Comment: glad it help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd be surprised if that worked. Have you tried calling it via `testbot().botfox()` ?

`webdriver.firfox` would not work, as the syntax is `webdriver.Firefox`
`webdriver.firfox(geckodriver)` would not work as `geckodriver` is not defined anywhere
`botfox()` would not work because there is no function defined as that. There is one inside of `testbot` but you would need to first instantiate the class and then call it via `testbot().botfox()`

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: The code snippet you provided in no way would work. Please give your actual code. You would definitely get at least 3 different errors with the code you provided. I've updated my answer